# Dependency injection on module.install

Tags: 8, installation, dependency-injection

How do I leverage dependency injection for drupal 8 when invoking my module.install->hook_install() mehtod?

Or do I have to use `\Drupal::` method at this point?

Comment: You don't. You have to call services through \Drupal::service or applicable call when in procedural code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, for procedural code in hooks you have to use the static service container wrapper `\Drupal`. Either to get a service or to use one of the predefined static functions. See for example:

*shortcut.install*

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function shortcut_install() {
  // Theme settings are not configuration entities and cannot depend on modules
  // so to set a module-specific setting, we need to set it with logic.
  if (\Drupal::service('theme_handler')->themeExists('seven')) {
    \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('seven.settings')->set('third_party_settings.shortcut.module_link', TRUE)->save(TRUE);
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool, that is what I thought, I just wanted to make sure my intuition was correct.  It's nice to know I'm not going insane.